# How to search for multiple databases for a specific table returning all rows and list the related database names

Tags: sql

Here is an example for what I’ve used to query for the information on one database.

```
select *
FROM DatabaseName.Act.User
where ukey = 2
order by createdate
```

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I’m using SQL...

Comment: Again: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database" (and is using SQL)

Answer (score 0):

you can use union/union all according to the requirement

```
select *,'DatabaseName.Act.User'  AS TableName
FROM DatabaseName.Act.User
where ukey = 2
order by createdate
UNION ALL
select *,'DatabaseName2.Act.User' AS TableName
FROM DatabaseName2.Act.User
where ukey = 2
order by createdate
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: The union all sound awesome, as I know the specific databases. But union all returns an error Incorrect syntax near keyword ‘UNION’. The other option returned an error database ‘databasename’ does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. I’m trying to search why union all is not working. Thank you so much in advance for your help. I’m new to this site and found this to be a great way to learn SQL

Comment: I built the query to union all and it worked great but when I changed it to to list all the ukey rows it dose not list all . . stops at row 3.  To clarify if I change ukey = 4 the the result is nothing or if I remove specific value (where ukey = 2) to list all it lists up to 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query if you are using sql server.  This will search specific table in all the databases

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery varchar(1000)
create table #user (DatabaseName varchar(128), ukey int) 
SELECT @SQLQuery = 'USE ? if exists (select top 5 * from sys.objects where [name] = ''user'' and schema_name(schema_id) = ''act'')
Begin
insert into #user (DatabaseName,ukey)
select db_name(),ukey FROM Act.[User] where ukey = 2 order by createdate
end' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQLQuery 
select * from #user
drop table #user
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.